# Select from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying to select value from different tables but i face some errors in the result i want to check if there is any values i will echo "Yes" otherwise echo "No"

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $username=$_POST['username'];


    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql="SELECT donator.national_id, needy_people.national_id".
       "FROM donator, needy_people".
           " WHERE donator.national_id='$username' OR needy_people.national_id='$username' limit 50";


    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($check>0){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

            $check=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
        }
    }

    if(isset($check)){
        echo'YES';
    }else{
        echo'Noooo';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

}else{
    echo'error';
}
```

can anybody solve this problem  help!

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `mysql` and `mysqli`?

Comment: No i just try any to solve it

Comment: Also, please post the error that you're getting.

Comment: i dont get the correct output.if should echo"yes" if there is a value. but it always echo"No"

Comment: Where did your `$check` variable come from?

Comment: it come from  //$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
 but when i write it give me error

Comment: Change `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)` to `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: i change it.. still always give me echo"NO"

Comment: `phpMyAdmin` a tool written in PHP to make it easier for ??? people to maintain a **MySQL database** MYSQL is the Database

Comment: Sensible code indentation. 1) Makes code easier to read. 2) Makes code easier to **debug**

Comment: No wonder so much international aid goes missing

Comment: Use parameterized queries

Comment: @RiggsFolly what are you trying to say

Comment: I am trying to say this code is nonsence

Comment: @RiggsFolly this code is just testing,

Comment: Why are you processing a loop for 50 occurances only to decide if there is a result from your query

Answer (score 0):

When you put as condition `if($check>0)`, `$check` is not defined yet, so it won't be processed, hence `$check` stay unset.
Also you should use the `empty()` function to test existence of values in it

Comment: the check is:  //$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
 but it give me another erroe

Comment: unless you define it elsewhere, here //$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql)); is defined in the if($check>0) statement, so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to check if a row exists when you run your query consider using the function [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Has row";
}
```

Comment: Or better still do a `COUNT` query

Comment: Has row! You guys crack me up

Comment: @RiggsFolly Good point! He would still have to run that query, and make a comparison though.

Comment: I would shoot for not doing a count. Unless in this hypothetical is all you want, is the count. Then, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

```
$count=mysqli_num_rows($check);
if($count>0)
echo "yes";
else
echo "no";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: yea, now we are getting to the crux of the question